# What library (or not) is Airbnb using for their slider toggles? (screenshot attached)

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

What library (or not) is Airbnb using for their slider toggles? Screenshot is attached. I'm curious to know. I took a look at their source, but could not identify the library.[image: Screenshot of sliders]

Answer (score 2):

I don't what their using, but it wouldn't be hard to recreate using transition and jquery.

```
#stage .slider-frame {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70px;
  height: 23px;
  background-color:#62C100;
  border-radius:50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0px#888;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0px #888;
}
#stage .slider-frame .slider-button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 23px;
  height: 21px;
  line-height: 27px;
  background: #FEFEFe;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#stage .slider-frame .slider-button.on {
  margin-left: 45px;
}
```

and then something like this:

```
$('.slider-button').toggle(function(){
    $(this)
        .addClass('on')
        .parent()
        .next('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .attr('checked', 'checked');
},function(){
    $(this)
        .removeClass('on')
        .parent()
        .next('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Mpb/)